# __unicode__ not called on some objects in Django/Python project when getting string representation

Tags: python, django

In **django**, why does defining `__unicode__` method on some types of objects (models, etc.) result in `print(obj)` printing the output of `__unicode__` but if I create my own classes, and define `__unicode__`, it doesn't seem to get called?  I've read about `__repr__`, but it seems like all the focus in Django is on `__unicode__`.

**What is the relationship between the two, and what is the best practice to get good string representations of my objects in my logs?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Django Model class [defines `__str__` for you](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode) with something like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')
```

Therefore, when you `print(obj)` (and `obj` is a `Model`), Python calls `obj.__str__()` which calls `unicode(obj)` which calls `obj.__unicode__()`.

If you create your own class and add a definition of `__str__` like the one above, then you can use `__unicode__` to return a unicode representation of your object, and have that one function also control the object's `str` representation.

Comment: Good catch inside Django :)